# startActivityForResult vs accessing a static variable for the result

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm wondering if there's any downside to accessing a static variable in one Activity from another Activity instead of calling startActivityForResult() and waiting for the result to come back.

In my example, I'm trying to retrieve a list of objects from a second activity. The first activity calls startActivityForResult. The second activity then allows a user to add different objects which CAN be stored statically in an ArrayList. But the way I'm doing it now is storing the objects in an SQLite table and then sending the column IDs back to the first Activity with Intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(). The first array then searches for these IDs in the SQLite table and re-creates the objects.

It would be way easier if I instead just accessed a static ArrayList of the checked items in the second activity. It works, but I am wondering if it is bad practice. If it's not bad practice, then the startActivityForResult() seems like a very convoluted way of exchanging data between two activities.

Comment: use startActivityForResult, it will be always clear than have some state, here and there set. And it will surely less error-prone

Comment: Or you could just put the operation in a static utility class and persist in SharedPreferences?

Comment: I have a Singleton that I use for some things, but whether it is good practice to use this sort of Singleton is pretty much the same question: should I use them (Singletons/static utility classes) if they can be avoided?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering if there's any downside to accessing a static variable in one Activity from another Activity instead of calling startActivityForResult() and waiting for the result to come back.

Memory leaks, for one.

> The second activity then allows a user to add different objects which CAN be stored statically in an ArrayList. But the way I'm doing it now is storing the objects in an SQLite table and then sending the column IDs back to the first Activity with Intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(). The first array then searches for these IDs in the SQLite table and re-creates the objects.

Replace your two activities with a single activity, perhaps using two different fragments. If these activities are that tightly coupled with that complex of data sharing, they should not be separate activities in all likelihood.

> If it's not bad practice, then the startActivityForResult() seems like a very convoluted way of exchanging data between two activities.

It is designed for simpler flows, such as picking an individual contact, where the "result" is small and `Parcelable`. `startActivityForResult()`, like `startActivity()` itself, is also designed to work across applications, where your solution will not work.

Comment: Thank you, this is the sort of answer I was hoping for. Generally I use Fragments when this sort of data is being exchanged, but the function I'm implementing is very similar to picking contacts, except that the end-user is presented with multiple choices. I originally used a Parcelable object, but as the object became more complex I thought that sending the IDs and reaccessing through SQLite would be easier.

Comment: @n00bface: "but the function I'm implementing is very similar to picking contacts" -- so? The only reason why picking contacts is handled via an activity is because it's not your activity. I'd still use fragments for this sort of a complex communications.

Comment: I've been looking at other apps with similar functionality since I asked this question and I'm now inclined to agree with you. Thank you for the advice.